How set value for textbox that created dynamic C#?
I created some textbox and labels dynamic the program with the following code:
public void DynamicObjects(int countRow)
{
    tableLayout.RowCount = countRow;
    tableLayout.ColumnCount = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < countRow; i++)
    {
        Label lblTitle = new Label();
        lblTitle.Text = i + "box";
        lblTitle.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        tableLayout.Controls.Add(lblTitle, 0, i);

        TextBox txtValue = new TextBox();
        txtValue.Text = "2";
        txtValue.Name = "txt_numberSabad" + i+1;
        tableLayout.Controls.Add(txtValue, 1, i);
    }
}

Now I want to set the value inside the program somewhere and I used the following code.
private void Form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DynamicObjects(5);
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)(tableLayout.Controls["txt_numberSabad"+3]);
    txt.Text = "new text for texBox";
}

But I get the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object


Re "txt_numberSabad"+3, you could have just written "txt_numberSabad3", by the way

Firstly, I'd personally suggest that you store your textboxes in a list or something similar so you don't have to access them by name.
But beyond that, I strongly suspect that the problem is that the control that you expect to have the name "txt_numberSabad3" actually has the name "txt_numberSabad21". Here's a short program to show why:
int i = 2;

string name1 = "txt_numberSabad" + i+1;
Console.WriteLine(name1);

string name2 = "txt_numberSabad" + (i + 1);
Console.WriteLine(name2);

The output is:
txt_numberSabad21
txt_numberSabad3

In this expression: "txt_numberSabad" + i+1 the precedence rules mean it's equivalent to ("txt_numberSabad" + i) + 1. To get the result you actually want, you need to evaluate i + 1 and then append that to the string:
txtValue.Name = "txt_numberSabad" + (i + 1);

